# Convert hex to string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to use `HEXTORAW()` to get the char value from the ASCII HEX code '30'.
ASCII HEX 30 should return varchar '0'.

How to to that? Is `HEXTORAW()` the right function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [utl_raw](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_raw.htm#BABJHEGF) package and [cast_to_varchar2()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_raw.htm#BABJFGBH) function specifically:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw('30')) as res
  from dual
```

result:

```
RES
-----
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`CHR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions026.htm#i76965) (for single characters):

```
SQL> select chr(to_number('30', 'XX')) from dual;

CHR(TO_NUMBER('30','XX'))
-------------------------
0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some difficulties using characters from the extended ascii range (ISO Latin‑1 ; ISO-8859‑1). Solved it like this:

```
select chr(to_number('D6','xx') using NCHAR_CS) from dual
```

where hex value 'D6' matches (extended) ascii value 214 or character 'Ö'

or in a function

```
create or replace function hex_to_ascii(TEXT_IN varchar2) 
RETURN varchar2
as
  TEXT_OUT varchar2(200);
  TEXT_MAN varchar2(200):=TEXT_IN;
BEGIN
  while length(TEXT_MAN)>0
  LOOP
    TEXT_OUT:=TEXT_OUT||chr(to_number(substr(TEXT_MAN,0,2),'xx') using NCHAR_CS);
    TEXT_MAN:=substr(TEXT_MAN,3);
  END LOOP;
  return TEXT_OUT; 
END;
```

The function can be used like this:

```
select hex_to_ascii('30D6D0D1C7DC') from dual
```

The input hex string '30D6D0D1C7DC' will be converted to '0ÖÐÑÇÜ'

I hope that this can be of use to others