# Sql conversion of ascii value to ascii string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In a following select:

`select value from A;`

I have this varchar output:`30313233` which after conversion of each character based on its ascii code representation equals `1234`.

Is there any way how to make this conversion automatically on SQL level? I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a WITH clause subquery to chop the string into tokens of two digit hex values. That output feeds into the main query [which converts the hex value into raw and then into characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19495447/146325), and uses LISTAGG() to stitch them back together.

```
with cte as ( 
    select substr('30313233', (level*2)-1, 2) as tkn
           ,level as id
    from dual
    connect by level <= length('30313233')/2
    ) 
select listagg(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw(tkn))) within group (order by id)
from cte
```

There is a [demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5266a6e8d17ec64f99eb9a6ae03e9719). Obviously your version of this code will rewrite the subquery to select the value from your table.

Incidentally, the input string is the hex representation of `0123`. The ASCII representation of `1234` would be `49505152` and requires a slightly different solution:

```
with cte as ( 
    select substr('49505152', (level*2)-1, 2) as tkn
           ,level as id
    from dual
    connect by level <= length('49505152')/2
    ) 
select listagg(chr(tkn)) within group (order by id)
from cte
```